# Add on tap function flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

hello guys i want to create an **onTap** option for my icon, my code is like this and I cant figure out how to do so can you help me.this is my code:

```
trailing: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        child: new Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: you can wrap Icon with inkwell and us ontap property.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `IconButton` instead.

```
new IconButton(
  icon: new Icon(Icons.bookmark),
  onPressed: () { /* Your code */ },
)
```

In your code, you can use like this

```
trailing: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        child: new IconButton(
                                 icon: new Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                                 onPressed: () { /* Your code */ },
                               ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: You can use above code to replace your "child: new Icon(Icons.bookmark),".

Comment: @serjomacken Please accept the answer which has worked for you. So others can use it.

Comment: children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.cloud_upload, color: UtilColors.blueColor), how  to add tap listenr on this.

Answer (score 12):

Create the button and Wrap it in a **GestureDetector** with an **onTap** callback

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Gesture Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(title: title),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: MyButton()),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Our GestureDetector wraps our button
    return GestureDetector(
      // When the child is tapped, show a snackbar
      onTap: () {
        final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Tap"));

        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      },
      // Our Custom Button!
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        child: Text('My Button'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Important :*** for user interactivity, you can use **onPressed** property.